# How to overide user selected attribute based on another attribute's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I want a checkbox selection to override the user's selected value for another attribute.

The form:

```
<%= form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
  <tr>      
    <th>FooType</th>
    <td><%= f.select :foo_type_id, options_from_collection_for_select(FooType.order(:name).all, "id", "name", @foo.cabinet_type_id) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Legacy Foo</th>
  <td><%= f.check_box :is_legacy %> </td>
</tr>
```

Where do I put code to overwrite the user's selection for :foo_type based on if :is_legacy is checked?  I tried adding an update_attribute command after saving the new Foo, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if @foo.save_standard and ! row.nil?
  #set foo type to 38u when it is a legacy foo
  if params[:is_legacy] == true
    @foo.update_attribute(foo_type_id, 2)
 end
```

Comment: Use `<%= f.check_box :is_legacy, true %>` (add the true value for the is_legacy param if we check this box) and maybe `if params[:is_legacy].to_s == 'true'`

Comment: That seems to still fail the same logic I have in place now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of mistakes in the following code:

```
if @foo.save_standard and ! row.nil?
  #set foo type to 38u when it is a legacy foo
  if params[:is_legacy] == true
    @foo.update_attribute(foo_type_id, 2)
  end
end
```

Try:

```
if @foo.save_standard && row
  if params[:foo][:is_legacy]
    @foo.update_attribute(:foo_type_id, 2) # careful, this method do not fire callbacks
  end
end
```

Assuming your instance object is a `Foo` class (which is probably not). If not, replace

```
params[:foo]
```

by whatever your instance class is.

Comment: You're right that they were mistakes, unfortunately it's keeping the user data still.

Comment: Thanks.  2 questions: why do you need to sometimes put the object type in the params[] call, and what does it mean that a method does not fire callbacks?

Comment: When using `form_for(@foo)` you tell rails to encapsulate the form values in `@foo` class name. More information on callbacks here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Also, I strongly recommend you take a look at this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html